# Deadlock: insert vs. select from several tables. Snapshot isolation?

Tags: sql, sql-server, deadlock

In my database I have two closely related tables.
There is a frequently called SP that INSERTs some rows into both tables within a transaction, and several other places that do SELECTs from these tables joined.

INSERTs take X locks on both tables, SELECTs take S or IS locks on them. Since the order in which shared locks are taken varies from query to query, some of them occasionally get deadlocked with the INSERT transaction.

Is there any good way to avoid these deadlocks (NOLOCK probably doesn't qualify as 'good')?

So far the only general solution I can think of is using SNAPSHOT isolation level. However, it would add some performance overhead, and I haven't yet found any sound data on how large this overhead is.

Comment: are your selects doing table scans?

Comment: Some of them may be doing scans (there're different SELECTS). Most of them should be using an index, so most likely seeks only.

Comment: set up a trace and use the deadlock graph, look at the actual SQL causing the deadlock.  anything else is just speculation guessing on locking and scans.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use snapshot in my system. It is not free, that's for sure, but the alternatives are not free either - blocking uses up resources too. Using rowlock does not always help.
Also snapshot gives you a consistent point in time snapshot of your data; otherwise you are exposed to some subtle bugs.

One more thing: you can get deadlocks even if you have only one table, examples here: [Reproducing deadlocks involving only one table](http://sqlblog.com/blogs/alexander_kuznetsov/archive/2009/01/01/reproducing-deadlocks-involving-only-one-table.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Does you SP select or update anything from these tables inside transaction? If not, you can try to use **rowlock** hints for your inserts and other selects (rowlocks usually do not escalate into page or table locks, unless you have too many rows in select results). If yes, then you can try **updlock** hint for your selects inside SP transaction.

Comment: Unfortunately, the problem manifests itself with row-level locking too. There is an index on one of the tables, INSERT transaction takes an X KEY lock on its value, and SELECT statement tries an S lock on it. Basically, the contention just moves to that index.

Comment: The index is on the bool column, so the KEY lock basically locks the whole "interesting" part of the table. So, in a sense, it does not differ much from a TAB lock. :-(

Comment: Even exclusive locking out entire table should not cause deadlocks - other selects just will wait until table is released. Are there any select statements inside SP transaction before actual insert statement?

Comment: Nope. There're two tables, hence the deadlock.

Answer (score 0):

[I'm not sure if this will help you but I found this blog awhile ago and it helped me cleanup some deadlocks.](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/bartd/archive/2006/09/09/747119.aspx)